# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS GNOME shows wrong battery status and refreshes much later

Tags: gnome, power-management, battery, charging

So I recently got this problem after dealing with Ubuntu as my first unix-based os.
After plugging my charger, battery status in top right corner is not changing, decreasing percentages. I checked my battery status from the terminal with the `udevadm info --path` command, the output is:

> E: POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Charging
> E: POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=39

At the same time GUI shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJTdX.png)

A couple of minutes later the GUI starts showing the proper icon and status.

When I unplug the charger, it does the same thing but the other way around(first showing 'charging' and then switching back to normal).

Checked the port by monitoring with `udevadm monitor`, output occurs on both plugging and unplugging, everything seems fine.
Let me know if you come up with a way to solve this problem.

Comment: You say Unity, but your screenshot seems to be from GNOME. Could you confirm whether you are using regular Ubuntu or Ubuntu Unity?

Comment: Looks like I keep learning(now that I've read more on the topic), I am using regular Ubuntu with GNOME.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Top Menu Battery indicator not showing correctly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317600/top-menu-battery-indicator-not-showing-correctly)

Comment: Well, It's more of a hack instead of fixing the actual problem. I'd prefer to have a more stable solution where Upower detects when the charger is plugged in and immediately switches the battery status in the gui.